# Does anything else like Unity Everyplay exist?

Tags: android, ios, screen-capture, everyplay

I'm looking for something like Everyplay that has an SDK for custom engines on Android.

Does anything like that exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of, there are screen capturing apps for both Android and iOS.  But they're not available normally (android needs to be rooted, iOS needs to be jailbroken or use an enterprise build).